# slicing a string with variables, Typerror: string indices must be integers

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a script that finds the substring 'bob' in a given string.  I thought string slicing would be a good way of doing it, but I'm getting "TypeError: string indices must be integers".  I'm confused by this as both of the variables I've used as indices are integers as far as I can tell.

Also even if this code is not an efficient way of doing this I am curious as to why I'm having issues using variables as indices as all of my googling has turned up that that is an okay thing to do.

```
s = 'azcbobobegghakliia'

bob = 'bob'
startindex = 0
endindex = 2
numBob = 0

while len(s) > endindex:
    if s[startindex,endindex] == 'bob':
        numBob += 1
        startindex += 1
        endindex += 1
print(numBob)
```

I expected it to print 2 as 'bob' is contained twice in this string (...bobob...).  The actual output is "TypeError: string indices must be integers"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comma-separated variables by default make a tuple. You want to use `:` to make a slice instead.

Longer explanation: `a[b,c]` is equivalent to `a[(b,c)]`, that is, `a` indexed with the tuple `(b,c)`. To get the elements from `b` to `c`, you need `a[b:c]`.